# ASA failover mode switching from Active/Active to Active/Standby

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, failover

We have two ASAs with failover set to Active/Active. This seems to work fine for everything we do except using VPN connections. It seems whenever the primary ASA fails over that all VPN connections are lost. I am new to configuring ASAs for HA but from what I've read I understand that failover must be set to Active/Standby in order for VPN connections to also failover. Correct?

Both ASAs have matching configurations for VPN with certificates installed and address pools assigned.

My question would be what would be required of me to switch the ASAs from Active/Active to Active/Standby?

Comment: Did you ever get a good answer on this? What was the solution?